# Customising Flex datagrid headerText

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, database, headertext

Gurus,
I have a Adobe AIR application which has a datagrid. My requirement is to allow the user to make the column headers and the number of columns of that grid, customizable.
 1. How can I get the column headerText values from DB?
 2. If the user can enter the column names, it has to be saved to the DB and then loaded.

Pl suggest.

Regards 
~Jad

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header text programmatically as follows (where dg is your datagrid id):

```
(dg.columns[0] as DataGridColumn).headerText = "Something"
```

Reading from and storing to the database can be done many ways.
To keep it simple, just create an httpservice in flex that invokes a php(or whatever your favorite scripting language) on the server side.

There is a simple example [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=7744) on Adobe cookbooks